# Javascript parenthesis format

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, parentheses

I'm a bit confused regarding the following parenthesis formats in Javascript:

```
(listeners = {})[obj._listenerId] = obj;
```

What does it mean when an object is surrounded by parentheses?

Same for this:

```
 ({
  value: "\\abc"
 })
```

What is the meaning of a file that contain only this code?

Comment: The second example is a file attached to the mustache.js framework, called backslashes.js - there are other similar examples there, that all they do is wrap object declarations with parentheses.

Comment: Then it might be just used to be able to evaluate the file as JavaScript. Without the parenthesis, the `{...}` would be evaluated as *block*, not as object literal, and it would throw a syntax error. It's again the grouping operator, but used to ensure that the "content" is evaluated as expression. It is not used to change the order of evaluation.

Comment: How can this expression be used?

Comment: I don't know. These files seem to be part of the mustache.js unit tests, which are run with Node.js. I wouldn't worry about how they are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses are the [*grouping operator*](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.6). With them you can change the order of evaluation of an expression.

What `(listeners = {})[obj._listenerId] = obj;` does is:

1. Assign an empty object to `listeners`.
2. Assign the value `obj` to the property `obj._listenerId` of that object.

Without the parentheses, the expression would be evaluated as (here I use the parentheses just to emphasize the evaluation order):

```
listeners = ({}[obj._listenerId] = obj);
```

i.e.

1. Assign `obj` to the property `obj._listenerId` of an empty object.
2. Assign `obj` to `listeners` (the result of an assignment expression is the assigned value).

---

I bet you already know the grouping operator from mathematical expressions. `1 + 2 * 3` will result in `7`. But `(1 + 2) * 3` is `9`. `*` has a higher precedence than `+` and you can change that with grouping.

MDN provides a [table of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) in the order of their precedence.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, parentheses are simply and classically used to change the order of executions, because accessing a property using the bracket notation has an higher precedence than assignation. It makes assignation occurs first.

Thus your line is equivalent to

```
listeners = {};
listeners[obj._listenerId] = obj;
```

In the second case, it's hard to tell without more code but those parentheses are probably used to avoid the parser think it's a code block. This expression returns a literal object.

Comment: If you want a link about using parenthesis to delimit an expression (and thus changing the execution order), the one provided by Felix is probably good.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are used so that the part inside them, is evaluated first.
For example `(listeners = {})` will return the new listeners empty object.

Answer (score 0):

this is a short notation of:

```
listeners = {};
listeners[obj._listenerId] = obj;
```

you can Try this:

```
(sameObj={})['key']='value';
console.log(sameObj)
```